Compatibility of various statements on congruent numbers and elliptic curves of the form $y^2=x^3-n^2x$
I would like to understand the connection between the three statements on the connection between elliptical curves and congruent number.
Three statements are strongly represented in the literature:

For $n\neq0$, let $E_n$ be the elliptical curve $y^2=x^3-n^2x$. The rational number $n$ is a congruent number if and only if there is a point $P=(x,y)\in E_n(Q)$ with $y\neq0$ (William Stein, "Elementary Number Theory: Primes, Congruences, and Secrets", Springer, page 144).
Wikipedia states that $n$ is a congruent number, if the corresponding elliptic curve $E_n$ has an infinite number of rational points (hence if the curve has a positive rank).
A well known fact tell us that $n$ is a congruent number if and only if the rank of the Mordell-Weil group over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the elliptic curve $ny^2=x^3-x$ is positive (Yongxiong Li, "Quadratic Twists of Elliptic Curves" in: Zhibin Liang, Chandrakant Aribam (eds.) "The Computational and Theoretical Aspects of Elliptic Curves", Springer, page 46).

The first statement seems to me to be a weaker condition than, for example, the 2nd statement.
In the 3rd statement, the equation of the elliptic curve deviates, since $n$ (not squared) is the coefficient of the $y^2$.
I would be very grateful for an easy-to-understand explanation of how these statements fit together.

The survey by K. Conrad is quite nice and explains this.

Thank you for this nice paper. I went through it. The only point I am missing there is: Why having one nontrivial point (where $y\neq0$) means the curve rank is positive? Why it means that we will have then infinitely many rational points on the curve $y^2=x^3-n^2x$?

If he rank of the elliptic curve over $\Bbb Q$ is $1$, then we have infinitely many rational points.

Yes - but why this holds?: If there is one nontrivial rational point on the curve, then there are infinitely many rational points. This implication is still not clear for me.

You are right, this implication is false in general, see this post. We really need that the rank is positive. One rational point is not enough. Rank $0$ means, that we have only finitely many rational points.

That post is interesting. Thank you. I am now thinking about the fact, that for the special case $y^2=x^3-n^2x$ this implication is true and the reason why in literature both statements are not contradictory.

Ok I found a proposition in literature, for example here on page 13: Let $n$ be a squarefree positive integer. Then $E_n(\mathbb{Q})_{tors}={\mathcal{O}, (0,0), (n,0), (-n,0)}$. Hence there are no torsion points with $y\neq0$. A rank zero curve is not possible then.
